# How to pass objects to a TemplateView?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am just learning CBVs and having a tough time with passing an object to a TemplateView. This has been pretty demoralizing as I know this should be very basic.

Here is my views.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.views import generic
from company_account.models import CompanyProfile

class CompanyProfileView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/company.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CompanyProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return CompanyProfile.objects.all()
```

And here is my Models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

Here is urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/companyprofile/$', CompanyProfileView.as_view()),
]
```

And finally, here is the template:

```
{% extends '_layouts/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Company Profile{% endblock %}

{% block headline %}<h1>Company Profile</h1>{% endblock %}

{% block content %}{{ CompanyProfile.company_name }}{% endblock %}
```

What am I missing? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There are few things you are doing wrong, but to help you we need to know what actually you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template *cannot* read the model `CompanyProfile`. You have to create an instance of the model first before you get any attribute.

Suppose you have the several instances of `CompanyProfile`:

CompanyProfile.objects.get(pk=1) --> this has a `company_name`="Adidas"
CompanyProfile.objects.get(pk=2) --> this has a `company_name`="Nike"

And suppose you want to display Nike and Adidas.

Then here's how you can do it:

```
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
   company_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class CompanyProfileView(views.TemplateView):
   template_name = 'my_template.html'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(CompanyProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       # here's the difference:
       context['company_profiles'] = CompanyProfile.objects.all()
       return context
```

Then, render your template like this:

```
{% for company in company_profiles %}
    {{ company.company_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: It worked! That was really helpful. The context bit had me confused but I get it now with your help. Thank you.